# How can I use SVG fragments and set background-size: cover?

Tags: css, svg, css-sprites

I have a problem with sizing of SVG image when I use [fragments](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fragment).
When I set `background-size: cover` the image does not covers available space in the container.

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-fragment-background-position-problem-2go4u).

Is it possible to use SVG fragments and be able to use `contain` and `cover` in `background-size` with proper behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're not specifying the width and height of the parent SVG. Chrome has a bug  that requires height and width to be specified for fragments to handle img related CSS techniques, not sure what the source of the info was but CSS Tricks documented it [here](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/). I think the height and width only needs to be specified in the parent SVG where the use tag is.

You can see here that setting the height and width for the svg tag in sprite.svg gives uniform behavior between both versions.

https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-fragment-background-position-problem-i75l3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately the need to specify width and height for the whole sprite will not allow to group images with different sizes into single sprite. Am I correct?